# Proper way of writing $(this).text().match(r) into vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

I have the following function written in jQuery which I would like to convert to javascript but I couldn't find a proper way so far.

```
const word = document.getElementById("searchField").value;
        const r = new RegExp("(" + word + ")", "ig");
$(".list-item").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).text().match(r)) {
                
            }
        });
```

I rewrote it this way:

```
const word = document.getElementById("searchField").value;
        const r = new RegExp("(" + word + ")", "ig");

        let pickComp = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
        Array.from(pickComp).forEach((i) => {
            if (//how can I rewrite the jQuery here?) {
                
            }
        })
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). `match` is a built-in method. In your `forEach`, `i` is _not_ the index, but the element itself.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks Sebastian for the tip regarding *i*

Comment: The documentation is here: [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters), [`match`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [`textContent`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: Also, `document.querySelectorAll` returns an iterable HTML collection, so you can `forEach` it directly, no need for `Array.from`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const word = document.getElementById("searchField").value;
const r = new RegExp("(" + word + ")", "ig");

const pickComp = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');

pickComp.forEach(item => {
      if (item.innerHTML.match(r)) {
        console.log("Match!!");
        }
      })
```

```html
<p class="list-item">abc</p>
<p class="list-item">abc</p>
<p class="list-item">abc</p>
<p class="list-item">abc</p>
<input id="searchField" value="abc">
```